# How To Use UILocalNotification In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to figure out how to setup a UILocalNotification in swift but I am not having a lot of luck. I am trying this:

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
var dateTime = NSDate.date()
notification.fireDate(dateTime)
notification.alertBody("Test")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

For starters, I am not sure if this is the proper way to get the current date time. In .Net, I would just do DateTime.Now().

Second, when I try this, I get an **error** that says:

> '(@lvalue NSDate!) -> $T3' is not identical to 'NSDate'

Unfortunately I have no idea what this means or how to proceed.

Comment: I also tried adding nil as the parameter for firedate. The documentation says if it's nil it should fire now. However I get basically the same error when I try that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you construct an `NSDate` using initializer syntax:

```
let dateTime = NSDate()
```

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/init) shows how ObjC convenience constructors map to Swift initializers. If the docs show an `init()` for a class, you call it using the name of the class: for `NSDate`, `init()` means you call `NSDate()`, `init(timeInterval:sinceDate:)` means you call `NSDate(timeInterval: x, sinceDate: y)`, etc.

Second: [`fireDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/fireDate) isn't a method, it's a property. You should assign to it instead of trying to call it:

```
notification.fireDate = dateTime
```

Ditto for `alertBody`.

You can also find the Swift syntax for Cocoa APIs by command-clicking a class name (or other API symbol) in your Swift source file; this causes Xcode to generate a "Swift-ified" version of the relevant header file.

Answer (score 7):

```
func setupNotificationReminder() {
    var title:String = "Your reminder text goes here"

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let calendarComponents = NSDateComponents()
    calendarComponents.hour = 7
    calendarComponents.second = 0
    calendarComponents.minute = 0
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    var dateToFire = calendar.dateFromComponents(calendarComponents)

    // create a corresponding local notification
    let notification = UILocalNotification()

    let dict:NSDictionary = ["ID" : "your ID goes here"]
    notification.userInfo = dict as! [String : String]
    notification.alertBody = "\(title)"
    notification.alertAction = "Open"
    notification.fireDate = dateToFire
    notification.repeatInterval = .Day  // Can be used to repeat the notification
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not answering your question but worth the note:

```
notification.fireDate(dateTime)
notification.alertBody("Test")
```

will also throw a compiler error saying that it can't find the init. do this instead

```
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15)
notification.alertBody = "Notification Received"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also support for creating the date like so:

```
NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, to cancel the particular local notification using Unique Key:

```
func cancelLocalNotification(UNIQUE_ID: String){

        var notifyCancel = UILocalNotification()
        var notifyArray = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications

        for notifyCancel in notifyArray as! [UILocalNotification]{

            let info: NSDictionary = notifyCancel.userInfo as! [String : String]

            if info[UNIQUE_ID]!.isEqual(UNIQUE_ID){

                UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notifyCancel)
            }else{

                println("No Local Notification Found!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to also separate out some of the components:

```
private let kLocalNotificationMessage:String = "Your message goes here!"
private let kLocalNotificationTimeInterval:NSTimeInterval = 5

private func LocalNotification() -> UILocalNotification {
  var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
  localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:kLocalNotificationTimeInterval)
  localNotification.alertBody = kLocalNotificationMessage
  return localNotification
}

private func ScheduleLocalNotificationIfPossible() {
  if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications()) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(LocalNotification())
  }
}
```

Now you can call, `ScheduleLocalNotificationIfPossible()` to schedule the local notification if the user has registered for remote notifications.