# ios-distinguish between background and lock screen with swift

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the problem. I want to develop a NStimer based APP to help students get rid of addiction in playing mobile phone.

When users try to move this app to background, the timer will be terminated and the mission is failed. But the timer will keeping running if the phone is just lock automatically and the mission will not be failed.

Is there any way to achieve this function?

Comment: I just tried all the function in AppDelegate.swift with println(). But it seems that iOS deal lock screen action and press home to move to background action with same procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSTimer` will not fire if you app is getting backgrounded. It may help to read up on the [application states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) of an iOS application.

One possible option that would to use [UILocalNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/) instead. A local notification gets registered with iOS and will fire whether your app is in the foreground or background or even terminated.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520024/how-to-use-uilocalnotification-in-swift) is a good thread to get you started with `UILocalNotification` in Swift.

Comment: It seems that CFNotificationCenterAddObserver is the way so far to solve my problem. But the examples I found were all based on ObjC